# Get input value from HTML5 input[type="date"] in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In chrome, a tag like

```
<input id="picker" type="date">
```

renders as a text field. However, calling trying to get its value with something like

```
$("#picker").val()
```

returns nothing until a valid date is entered or picked from it's dropdown.
I took a look at all of the object's immediate properties on a keypress with

```
$("#picker").keypress(function() {
    var output = ""
    for (var i in this) {       
        output += i +" value:"+ this[i] + "\n";
    }
    alert(output);
});​
```

but couldn't see my input in any of these. Check for yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/5cN2q/

My question is: Is it possible to get the text from a input[type="date"] in chrome when the input is not a valid date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [W3C Date State spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-state-%28type=date%29) defines the sanitization algorithm:

> - The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string instead.

Which is invoked whenever setting the value of the input element, as defined in [DOM input value spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value):

> - On getting, it must return the current value of the element. On setting, it must set the element's value to the new value, set the
>     element's dirty value flag to true, **invoke the value sanitization
>     algorithm**, if the element's type attribute's current state defines
>     one, and then, if the element has a text entry cursor position, should
>     move the text entry cursor position to the end of the text field,
>     unselecting any selected text and resetting the selection direction to
>     none.

So the `value` property will always be an empty string when the date is not valid. There doesn't seem to be any property for "original/dirty/user-typed text value" specified as it is not a text input after all.

IMO it is a good thing, it facilitates form validation as invalid dates are treated as falsy values (empty strings), it also leaves browsers to more freely implement the UI for date inputs.

If you prefer a non-W3C date input, you can use a text input with the good old JS date validation and a datepicker, such as the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). This would allow you to retrieve the actual text value of the input and is a much more cross-browser solution as well.

Comment: Ah. Makes enough sense given what I saw. My concern with Chrome's implementation is the lack of ability to do custom validation; Their textbox-based implementation gives the user the ability to enter whatever string they like, but gives me no ability to assist other than to check if val() === "" and alert.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty I'm using Chrome Canary at the moment (Version 25), this version has a very sturdy validation that does not allow entering invalid date values at all (unlike the current stable). Hopefully it will be implemented in the stable release soon, and others browsers will hopefully follow. `=]`

Answer (score 4):

As [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278250/2792078) you can't see the original value, you can however handle validation with `ValidityState`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  var inputdate = document.getElementById("inputdate")
  // check if date is valid.
  // you can use `inputdate.validity.valid` too.
  if(inputdate.validity.badInput) {
    // error message from the browser
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = inputdate.validationMessage
  }
  //document.myform.submit();
}
</script>

<div>message: </div><div id="message" style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"></div>
<form method=post action="./post">
  <input type="date" id="inputdate" value="2016-02-29">
  <a href="javascript: submitform()">get date!</a>
</form>
```

If you change the day to 30 and click the link, you'll see an error message.

Enjoy it.